# How can I convert a flat json file having rows of variable lengths to a csv file?

Tags: python, json, csv

Here is an example of the data I have.

```
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"},
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5"},
{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5", "f":"6"}
```

I want the csv as:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I tried different converters online, but as the json file is about 10 mb, I am unable to convert it online.

Comment: Why do you want to use your data as header? By data I mean the keys' value.

Comment: I meant having headers as a,b,c,d,e,f.

Comment: What happens if the input has a row `{"b":"2", "c":"3"}`? Also do you mean to have commas at the end of each line?

Comment: in case of {"b":"2", "c":"3"}
this row will have no value for a,d,e,f. No comma not need at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import json

with open('in.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

headers = set()
for row in data:
    headers.update(row.keys())

with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

`in.json`:

```
[
  {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"},
  {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5"},
  {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5", "f":"6"}
]
```

`out.csv`:

```
a,c,b,e,d,f
1,3,2,,,
1,3,2,5,4,
1,3,2,5,4,6
```

Comment: What if I dont define the headers manually? Also my data is in a json file.

Comment: @Thanks Alex, I tried the above code but I am getting this error
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1946-1948: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Also will it give the same same result if some of the rows are not in proper order such as:
[
  {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"},
  {"d":"4","a":"1", ,  "e":"5","b":"2", "c":"3"},
  {"f":"6","a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5"}
]

Comment: @Fawad yes it will handle order correctly. Your file has non-ASCII characters in it, you will need to know what the encoding is. Check out chardet.

Comment: Good. Make sure you read and write it taking that into account. Use this for the writing: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
o = ({"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"},{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5"},{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5", "f":"6"})

header_row = []

# gets the header
for row in o:
    for key, value in row.iteritems():
        if not key in header_row:
            header_row += key
            print(key + ',', end='')

# goes through the data
for row in o:
    for header_cell in header_row:
        if header_cell in row:
            print(row[header_cell] + ',', end='')
        else:
            print(',', end='')
```